# Adding anchor with joomla article menu

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

I'm using Joomla latest version.

My website url is http://beta.ahaliaexchange.com/

I want to navigate into maincontent area for inner pages without loading the slider.

Comment: People are posting answers to which your saying it's not what you want. Given this is the case, you might want to explain in more detail **exactly** what you're trying to achieve, and possibly mention what you've already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility)? While the options seem to be experimental, browser support for the basic feature is pretty good. So you'd add the javascript to the page somewhere below the content and have the script get element by id of the maincontent, then use scrollIntoView on the element.

Comment: actually i want to make anchor with joomla article menu

Comment: @ashley Sorry, but I have no idea what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your slider is a module, and it looks like it's published to a position called "Banner" (or similar).

You can control on what pages a module is visible using the "Menu assignment" settings.

Go to **Extensions** -> **Module manager**. Locate your slider module in the list, and click the name to open it. In the "Menu Assignment" tab, choose **Only on the pages selected** from the dropdown list, and check only the pages where you want the module to be visible, e.g. "Home":

[image]

Comment: i doesn't mean to hide or remove slider.but i want to navigate the below area of slider

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to do, can you explain a little more?

Comment: i mean when i clicking the menu want to focus on the maincontent area(i mean component area)
for example:by using #tag

Comment: You want to scroll down to the main article once the menu item is clicked? Like **About us** -> **[Anhalia Group](http://beta.ahaliaexchange.com/index.php/about-company#company-profile)** does? You could [implement something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432656/scroll-to-a-div-using-jquery) using jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: user want to remove that scrolll down and does not need to hide slider also....that was the issue..is there was any solution for that